# Importrange & Indirect automate function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use index match formula but the sheet in another workbook, the problem is i don't want to change the sheet manually in every function. see below what im expected, i already used indirect function but didn't work.
[image]

Comment: Please don't use raster images of text rendered to present (main) text parts of posts: paste the text, use a block quote/code block as appropriate. While you're at it: (much) more effort goes into reading any single post than into writing it. Do what helps reading when writing, for one thing, use proper capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

To make things less complicated and have the formula shorter, consider having your importrange data in another sheet (ex: Sheet 2) within the same workbook/ spreadsheet file, then implement your index-match in a normal way referencing to the other sheet, instead of doing indirect and importrange within one formula. This way you can easily troubleshoot if the index-match is returning the right/ desired value.

You can slo hide the sheet with the importrange data in case it's causing unnecessary view in your file.